# Completely reinstall everything on the Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, firmware

Let's say that I am paranoid and I want not only to wipe and reinstall OS X, but also recovery, SMC, firmware and everything in the Mac hardware that could have been infected with malware. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: and you do not want to just buy a new Mac

Comment: @Buscar웃SD: I am not paranoid enough.

Comment: Actually, I heard you can get infected by visiting this question.

Answer (score 1):

You could get a brand new SSD disk and install OS X on it, carefully clean wipe the current one.

In addition you could get EFI and SMC firmware from Apple.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT1557

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518

The before you do anything (since the malware could creep right in again) install something like LittleSnich and block everything from to Network and only allow fully trusted stuff.

Comment: Can I wipe all partitions, including hidden ones, to achieve the effect of new SSD?

Comment: You can wipe both the main and recovery partition on your drive.

Comment: Won't an old-school magnet delete all it?

Comment: @user125447 Disk utility does not show any hidden volumes. What other tools to use?

Comment: in terminal type "diskutil list" that should show you all disks/partitions you have, it will show EFI, Recovery HD among others. In disk utility enable the Debug mode to see them. Quit Disk Utility and in Terminal " defaults write com.apple.DiskUtility DUDebugMenuEnabled 1 " . Now open the disk utility and take a look. Be aware those are hidden on purpose so take care what you do.